# Can I use the NDK to build command line apps on Android?

Tags: android, c++, c, gcc, android-ndk

On a Linux machine, I can write a simple C program, compile it with gcc, and execute it from a command line. I'm trying to see if I can do similar with the NDK. Aside from that, perhaps as an alternative, would it be possible to use gcc and specify a different compiler for the Android device? I'd be interested in both ARM and x86 based Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

The NDK contains a document explaining how to do this in "docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html".

(Update: it looks like recent versions of the NDK put this document in `"docs/Programmers_Guide/html/md_3__key__topics__building__s_t_a_n_d_a_l_o_n_e-_t_o_o_l_c_h_a_i_n.html"`. It might be easier to open the top-level "NDK Programmer's Guide" in a browser and navigate to the "Building/Standalone Toolchain" section).

Once you've set up the environment variables pointing to the NDK toolchain or you have created an NDK cross-tools directory (as described in the document), building C programs for the Android environment is straightforward.

As a side note, the document has two sections on how to invoke the compiler:

- 3/ Invoking the compiler (the hard way)

and

- 4/ Invoking the compiler (the easy way)

I found "the hard way" to be easier to get going initially to try things out.  Once I performed a couple builds that way, I used "the easy way" to create a cross-tools directory that's easier to use on an on-going basis.

Comment: I see, I'll try this out. For the moment, I'm not seeing the docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html file. I'm going to download the NDK again.

Comment: I got it working, but I keep getting magic 7F45. What's the easiest way to figure out which toolchain and cross compiler I should use?

Comment: Sounds like you're not really doing a cross-compile. What does the  `file` command say about the executable?

Comment: What kind of device are you targeting first? Which `SYSROOT` did you choose?  `arch-arm` or `arch-x86`?

Comment: I should have mentioned this before. The device is a Nexus 5 (rooted but ro.secure is set to 1) running Lollipop. I have SYSROOT = $NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm and CC = $NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9. I'm doing this on an Ubuntu machine. I'm not sure if the version of gcc matters. I see 4.8, and another that doesn't list a version number.